# Javascript image scroller, how to keep it scrolling without restarting?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script that scrolls images vertically from bottom till the top and it works pretty good except for one thing. I would like this scrolling to be infinite and not to restart every time the frame is empty. In other words, I don't want it to be empty at any time.

You guys think this is possible? Here's the code (I know the script is pretty awful but I've tried so many and this is only one that did the trick for me):

```
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000" onMouseover="scrollspeed=(current/2)" onMouseout="scrollspeed=current" OnLoad="NewsScrollStart();">

<div id="NewsDiv">
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="200" align="center"><tr><td>
    <p>
    <!-- CLIENTS IMAGES--><img src="images/clients/tango.jpg" "width="100" height="37" align="middle" border="0"></p>
    <p><br>
      <br>

      <a target="newwindow" href="http://www.adbid.se" onClick="popup"><img src="images/clients/adbid_clients.png" border="0" align="middle"></a></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a target="newwindow" href="http://www.sanomadigital.nl"><img src="images/clients/logo_sanoma_digital.png" border="0" align="middle"></a></p>
    <p><a target="newwindow" href="http://www.sanomadigital.nl"><br />
      </a>

      <a target="newwindow" href="http://www.prisabs.com"><img src="images/clients/logo-prisa-bs-home.jpg" border="0" align="middle"></a></p>
    <p><a target="newwindow" href="http://www.prisabs.com"><br />
      </a>

    <a target="newwindow" href="http://www.sanoma.fi"><img src="images/clients/sanoma_logo.gif" border="0" align="middle"></a></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
     <table width="101" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="112" align="center"><img src="images/clients/echo.jpg" border="0" width="91" height="41"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p><br>
      <br>

      <a target="newwindow" href="http://www.familjeapoteket.se"><img src="images/clients/familjeapoteket_clients.jpg" border="0" align="middle"></a></p>
    <p><br />

      <a target="newwindow" href="http://www.hertz.se"><img src="images/clients/hertz_clients.jpg" border="0" align="middle"></a></p>
    <p><a target="newwindow" href="http://www.hertz.se"><br />
      </a>

      <a target="newwindow" href="http://www.gemoney.no"><img src="images/clients/gemoney_clients.jpg" border="0" align="middle"></a></p>
    <p><a target="newwindow" href="http://www.gemoney.no"><br />
      </a>

      <a target="newwindow" href="http://www.vikingline.se"><img src="images/clients/vikingline_clients.jpg" border="0" align="middle"></a></p>
    <p><a target="newwindow" href="http://www.vikingline.se"><br />
      </a>

      <a target="newwindow" href="http://www.ebookers.be"><img src="images/clients/ebookers_clients.gif "border="0" align="middle"></a></p>
    <p><a target="newwindow" href="http://www.ebookers.be"><br />
      </a>

      <a target="newwindow" href="http://www.ticket.se"><img src="images/clients/ticket_clients.gif" border="0" align="middle"><br />
      </a></p>
      </a></p>

</td></tr></table>
</div>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var scrollspeed     = "2"       // SET SCROLLER SPEED 1 = SLOWEST
var speedjump       = "40"      // ADJUST SCROLL JUMPING = RANGE 20 TO 40
var startdelay      = "0"       // START SCROLLING DELAY IN SECONDS
var nextdelay       = "0"       // SECOND SCROLL DELAY IN SECONDS 0 = QUICKEST
var topspace        = "10px"        // TOP SPACING FIRST TIME SCROLLING
var frameheight     = "500" // IF YOU RESIZE THE WINDOW EDIT THIS HEIGHT TO MATCH



current = (scrollspeed)


function HeightData(){
AreaHeight=dataobj.offsetHeight
if (AreaHeight==0){
setTimeout("HeightData()",( startdelay * 1000 ))
}
else {
ScrollNewsDiv()
}}

function NewsScrollStart(){
dataobj=document.all? document.all.NewsDiv : document.getElementById("NewsDiv")
dataobj.style.top=topspace
setTimeout("HeightData()",( startdelay * 1000 ))
}

function ScrollNewsDiv(){
dataobj.style.top=parseInt(dataobj.style.top)-(scrollspeed)
if (parseInt(dataobj.style.top)<AreaHeight*(-1)) {
dataobj.style.top=frameheight
setTimeout("ScrollNewsDiv()",( nextdelay * 1000 ))
}
else {
setTimeout("ScrollNewsDiv()",speedjump)
}}


</script>
```

Thanks you in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a copy of the image immediately following the one you are scrolling and scroll both. Once the first image leaves the screen completely and the copy is on screen, put the first image behind the copy and continue scrolling until the copy is off screen and the original is completely on screen. If you keep repeating this, you should get the illusion of an infinitely scrolling image.

Comment: @Justin Pearce: I tried that but unfortunately it doesn't change anything. I don't know why, but I tried putting a copy of images below the original ones. Somehow it does not work at all :/

Comment: Justin is on the right track.  This is how I have the 'continuous' scrolling on http://www.eze2go.com/000001 - The only difference is technique.  If you nest two elements one twice as wide as the other, then style them so that the outer element's scroll bar appears, all you have to do is hide the scroll bar, and animate the outer elements scrollTop or scrollLeft property.  If you look at http://www.eze2go.com/js/scroller.js, you can see all it does it test whether incrementing the scrollbar's position actually did anything, if it had no effect, then start over.  Most of the pain is in the css.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski: Your script looks very promising. I tried using my images with your script but it won't start. All I did was changing ScrollLeft to ScrollTop, but it didn't do the trick.

Here's what I've written after the css/html:

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');

function scroll()
{
 var scrollTop = scroller.scrollTop;
 scroller.scrollTop = scroller.scrollTop + 1;
 if(scroller.scrollTop == scrollTop) scroller.scrollTop = 0;
}

setInterval(scroll, 25);
</script>

Comment: @Jaoza Media: It all hangs on what element is referred to by 'scroller' and how it's styled.  To troubleshoot, don't hide the scrollbar and make sure the JavaScript is moving it.  If it's not moving, you're not referencing the element properly, if it's moving but it's contents aren't scrolling, then that's probably a styling issue.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski: I've tried many different alternatives of your script now and it stops working when I'm changing scrollLeft to ScrollTop. Looks like I have to check for something else.. :(

Comment: @Jaoza Media: it _is_ scrollTop, not ScrollTop, I'm sure that's just a typo in your comment.  Your HTML containing element does have a vertical scrollBar then does it?  If there's no scroll bar, then setting scrollTop will have no effect.  You can hide the scrollBar in CSS once you have it working.